# Excel Sum function - Don't return 0 if a range is blank

Tags: excel

I am using Excel 2013. I am using Sum function to find the sum of a range of cells. But if that entire range is blank, then 0 should be displayed. any help

Comment: re: *'But if that entire range is blank, then 0 should be displayed'* Are you saying that summing a range of blank cells does NOT return zero?

Comment: Summing a range of blank cells does return 0. I am using this formula across the entire column and so it would not look good if there are Zeros when there is no data in the columns beside it.

Comment: I'd suggest a custom or accounting style number format that does not show zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

Use COUNT to see if there are any numbers in the range, e.g.

```
=IF(COUNT(B1:B10),SUM(B1:B10),"")
```